# Get all data with 2 different values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
id        name        email_account
 1        Matt            hotmail
 2        Matt             yahoo
 3        Luis            hotmail
 4        Rita             gmail     
 5        Samy            hotmail
 6        Rita             yahoo
```

As you can see from this table, Matt has both a hotmail and a yahoo account. Rita also has 2 email accounts (gmail and yahoo). How do I (with SQL in MySQL) get all the people in this table that has at least 2 different email accounts (like Matt and Rita)

Comment: What if they are different people with the same name? Your schema doesn't look right.

Comment: They are the same people. It's perfectly legal for one person to have many different email accounts

Comment: So how are you accommodating people who have identical names?

Comment: if Matt has two hotmail accounts will you count it as 1 or 2?

Comment: If Matt has two hotmail account, that's just ONE. But if he has a hotmail and a yahoo account, that's TWO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT name
FROM Table
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(email_account) > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT name
FROM my_table
GROUP BY name HAVING count(email_account) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 1)` ...?

I wouldn't recommend this though. Instead, create another column.

Or in MySQL:

`SELECT name, COUNT(name) FROM orders
  GROUP BY table
  HAVING COUNT(name) > 1`

This will select people with duplicate names, which means, same people with different email accounts.